# SFTP: check if downloaded correctly

Tags: bash, sftp

I need to download some data from some SFTP connection and delete if on that FTP afterwards. But I have to be sure to have downloaded the data correctly.

At the moment I just do this in my script run by a cron:

```
sftp -oIdentityFile=key user@server <<EOF
    mget -r *
    mdelete *
    bye
EOF
```

But I worry that if a download breaks because of any reason the files get deleted anyway, since the FTP connection just works the next command without breaking the connection after a failed action.

I need to be sure the files have been downloaded correctly, best would be a hash compare. But since I heavily doubt FTP offers that function, what would be the best solution to solve that problem?

IF NOT possible:
It might be a workaround to leave all the files on the FTP server and just download the new ones. This seems to be a way easier solution. Any advice for this solution?

EDIT:
Since I have no influence on the server whatsoever, I am searching for the most practicable solution to be sure to download all files before they get deleted. I am not so much worried about the integrity of the data itself (I do trust ssh there).

Comment: Hash compare is the way to go, which will require that on the server side a hash file is also written, downloaded, and checked by the client. See RFC 4130 for a standardized version of this process over HTTP.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have influence on the served data.

Comment: The sftp server doesn't provide a hashsum of the file? To what would you compare it to, then?

Answer (score 1):

Simple `sftp` scripts like yours are fine for quick-and-dirty fetch scripts, but are a disaster waiting to happen when you use them to also delete files (especially wildcard deletions).

One very obvious danger with your script is that the `mdelete *` will delete not only the files that were in the directory when you ran `mget -r *` but also everything that was uploaded to the source directory after you started the `mget` - even files that weren't included in the `mget`.

There are several other (safer) alternatives for you.  Here's two:

1. Use [sshfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sshfs) to mount the sftp directory somewhere on your system.  Then you can use standard unix commands like `cp`, `mv`, `rm`, `rsync` etc to move files around.  This is by far your best option.
2. Write a program in a language that has an sftp library (e.g. perl or python. and most common & current compiled languages too) to connect to the remote server and:

   - get a list of files to transfer
   - for each file:

     - download it
     - validate it somehow (e.g. as @thrig suggested with an md5sum file or similar)
     - if it's OK, delete it from the remote server

Comment: I will write a python script to solve that problem. Thank you

Comment: i recommend sshfs and rsync.  rsync even has a `--remove-source-files` option to remove files that were **successfully** transferred.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the server, can't change protocol, can't use the native hashing extension (I assume).

Comment: you don't need to change the server to use `sshfs`.   the server's already running `sftp`, you run `sshfs` on the client side.  As far as the server is concerned, it's just another sftp client.

Comment: I just now realized that SFTP is not SSH in FTP, but FTP in SSH, nice! Thank you for that suggestion, would upvote if I wasn't a noob.

Comment: I mounted it as sshfs and `rsync --remove-source-files` it. Should be a flawless solution, right?

Comment: nothing's flawless, but it's a good solution.  and you'll need a few more rsync options than just `-remove-source-files` :).  See the man page.  and you can use rsync's `--dry-run` option while testing to make sure it's going to do what you expect.